# Android x PC local wireless communication without being through W-iFi or Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, p2p, wifi-direct

I have a project where an Android device is supposed to send and receive data from a local server.

For bureaucratic reasons, Wi-Fi technology cannot be used, and Bluetooth may not have enough range, so, is there any other option to do this communication?

Wi-Fi Direct seems to be a good option, but I have never used before.

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: Wifi direct is also wifi technology.

Comment: As greenapps said, Wi-Fi Direct requires you to have Wi-Fi enabled. You don't have to be connected to a network to communicate, but you still use Wi-Fi.